# Реально ли в Unity, в процессе анимации, в коде чётко контролировать кадры анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Реально ли в Unity, а именно в работе с анимацией, в коде, чётко контролировать кадры анимации. Идея в чём, нужно сделать объект который показывает перегрев оружия, то есть плашка, изменяющая размер и цвет во время стрельбы, и уменьшающаяся без стрельбы.

Проблема в том что банально не могу найти способ, реверсной (обратной) анимации, как вариант, было бы здорово контролировать через каждый кадр, то есть обратно было бы `переменная--`.

Жду конструктива, ярости и полезных советов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.speed = 0f;
anim.Play(string stateName, int layer, float normalizedTime(0f->1f));
// или
anim.PlayInFixedTime(string stateName, int layer, float fixedTime);
```

На тему реверса, если не ошибаюсь `speed` можно установить отрицательный.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, понимаю что подобрались мы близко, но выскочили неожиданные проблемы, некоторые от незнания.

"stateName"- что нужно поставить вместо него?
string int float выдают ошибку все вместе синхронно)))

Не совсем понимаю как это решается, если есть возможность Поможіть.